# Why OptionT does not work for Try?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am looking at this question from Scala and Scalaz angles. `OptionT` works for `Future` but not `Try`. What is the reason there is no `OptionT` for `Try` where there is a usecase a function i.e. `def foo(i: Int): Try[Option[Int]] = ...` may or not return a value and occasionally network exception will happen? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is [Try isn't a valid functor](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-outlaws#try).

You'll need to use scalaz-outlaws or write your own Try instances. Here's a working example using [scalaz-outlaws' Try instances](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-outlaws/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaz/outlaws/std/Try.scala#L7-L20):

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

implicit val tryOutlawInstances = new Traverse[Try] with Monad[Try] with Plus[Try]{
  def point[A](a: ⇒ A): Try[A] = Success(a)
  override def map[A,B](fa: Try[A])(f: A ⇒ B) = fa map f
  def bind[A,B](fa: Try[A])(f: A ⇒ Try[B]) = fa flatMap f
  def traverseImpl[F[_], A, B](fa: Try[A])(f: A ⇒ F[B])(implicit F: Applicative[F]) : F[Try[B]] = fa match {
    case Success(a) ⇒ F.map(f(a))(Success.apply)
    case Failure(f) ⇒ F.point(Failure(f))
  }
  def plus[A](a: Try[A], b: ⇒ Try[A]) = a orElse b
}

val foo = Try("foo".some)
val result = OptionT(foo).map(x => x.toUpperCase).run
```